# HTML Link opening a page that Redirect to a Quicktime .MOV file displays garbage characters in IE when Target is _blank

Tags: html, internet-explorer, redirect, quicktime, target

I have a .NET page that does a Response.Redirect to a Quicktime .mov file. When I create a link to this .NET page, if the link opens in the same window (i.e. no Target defined on the anchor tag), all is good and IE displays the Quicktime movie just fine. However if I set the Target of the link to "_blank" which opens a new window, IE displays garbage characters on the screen (as if you open a binary file). The URL in both cases (with or withotu target) is correct (i.e. http://localhost/movies/myMovie.mov). This is really puzzling...

Using Fiddler I can see that in both cases when the actual movie file is served after redirection, the content-type is video/quicktime which is correct.

Of course everything is good if I link directly to the .MOV files instead if a page that redirect to it but due to a business logic, I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, before you redirect, make sure you set Response.ContentType to "video/quicktime".